# Compare nullable types in WHERE clause of Linq to Sql VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

I am trying to query for records where that column IS NULL:

```
 Dim UnassignedSubSvc =
 (From c In CurrentContext.SubService
 Where c.Product.ProductSubServiceId  **is null**
 Select c).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim UnassignedSubSvc =
 (From c In CurrentContext.SubService
 Where Not c.ProductSubServiceId.HasValue
 Select c).ToList()
```

Nullable types use `HasValue` to indicate they contain a non-null value, so simply negating that will be enough.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error HAsvalue is not a member of integer

Comment: Then your `ProductSubServiceId` isn't set as nullable in the meta-data file (.edmx file). Fix your database schema.

Comment: ProductSubServiceID is refertial key in the table.

Comment: If it's a key it can't be null.